# How to debug dart file executed in java app in IntelliJ

Tags: java, dart, intellij-idea

I execute a dart file inside a java file and I have no idea how to debug that dart file.
This is how I run the java file passing the dart file to be executed:
[image: Configuration]
Output when running it in debug mode:
[image: Run]

My dart file: `Test.dart`

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("Hello World");
}
```

My Java file: `Main.java`

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("test", true, "Test Dart");
        CommandLine cmd = new DefaultParser().parse(options, args);
        if (cmd.hasOption("test")) {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec(cmd.getOptionValue("test"));
            String line;
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to set a break point in my dart file and automatically jump in it when it is executed inside the java file.
How do I do this?
[image: Breakpoint]

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-dart-remote-debug.html ?

Comment: Yes, and I still have no idea how to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically asking for is the ability to just debug a executable. Java does not even know anything about the dart process you are spawning since this is a OS call. If you want to debug the Dart program, you would need to use the Dart VM to execute your Dart program (maybe you are already doing that) and then add the argument:

```
dart.exe --enable-vm-service --pause_isolates_on_start yourProgram.dart
```

You can just do this from your Java program. The important part is just you are able to provide these arguments and then also output what the process are returning on STDOUT since it is needed in a later step.

You don't need the `pause_isolates_on_start` but it will make this a lot easier since it will halt the Dart program until the debugger have been attached.

You can then (if you have installed the Dart plugin in IntelliJ) create a `Dart Remote Debug` run profile:
[image]

As it describes, it will ask for a Dart service protocol URL when this debug profile are started like this:

[image]

The URL will be returned when you are starting your program with the arguments I mentioned previously like this:

```
> dart --enable-vm-service --pause_isolates_on_start .\bin\program.dart
The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8181/uyTMJ3eWnMM=/
The Dart DevTools debugger and profiler is available at: http://127.0.0.1:8181/uyTMJ3eWnMM=/devtools/#/?uri=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8181%2FuyTMJ3eWnMM%3D%2Fws
```

The URL your need to enter is, in this example, `http://127.0.0.1:8181/uyTMJ3eWnMM=/`.

If this is done correctly, and you are set a breakpoint before doing this, your IntelliJ should break into your Dart program as it starts executing after the debugger has been attached.